# Sending text file to Jenkins via remote trigger - from excel (VBA)

Tags: vba, jenkins

I have a job in Jenkins that accepts a text file parameter.
Builds are triggered from an excel macro - and I'm having difficulty understanding how to send the file to Jenkins.

Up until now, what I understood is the following:

- the file must be sent in an HTTP POST request, in the body.
- the file must be sent in multipart/form-data format.

What I can't seem to manage to find out:

- how exactly do I encode my file to multipart/form-data in VBA?
- how do I send multiple files to Jenkins in the same HTTP POST request?

More information that might be helpful:

- I'm using MSXML2.XMLHTTP60.
- The job has other parameters (string, password), so I'm using the format:
  http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?PARAM1=Value1&PARAM2=Value2

Thank you in advance for any help.

**EDIT:**

After a lot of headeache, I discovered that currently, the option of sending a file parameter via an http POST request is not supported:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-56169

But it has been opened as a new feature request.

The only option is pretending to be the web browser, and sending an http POST request identical to the one the Jenkins server is expecting to receive.
This poses the problem I described in the Jenkins Issue - the server's response doesn't contain the item's location in the queue.